# Should we vote to close dupe questions or dupe pairs question/answer?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50777173/ggplot2-one-regression-line-per-category?noredirect=1#comment88561841_50777173) is a possible dupe and 2 users, [Hack-R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3604745/hack-r) and [Henrik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1851712/henrik) have voted to close (which it was, given Henrik's gold tag badge).

When looking at the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25752909/multiple-ggplot-linear-regression-lines) and answer, I realized that the new answer was completely different and probably helpfull to other users in the future. So I made a comment on that and Hack-R suggested that maybe I should ask on Meta whether we shouldn't start closing duplicate question-answer pairs instead of just duplicate questions.

So that is the question: what to do in these cases?

Comment: Technically they are not the same question.  But always hard to make the call with RTFM questions, one good answer does have a knack for solving ten problems.  it doesn't get to be a duplicate until 5 [r] users agree it is, the ball is in their court.

Comment: Cheers, I think we should update the site rules with some sort of merger or intra-SO migration to reflect this situation. For instance the new answer could get added to the old question and the new question could redirect to the old. +1

Comment: @Rui Barradas As you probably have noted, when I closed the question I also changed the linked Q  originally suggested by Hack-R to a, in my opinion, more appropriate one.

Comment: @Hack-R: Mods can merge questions when it's warranted.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What does "close duplicate question-answer pairs" mean? Are you saying that identical questions with very different answers shouldn't be closed as duplicates?

Comment: @Aran-Fey Yes, that is the question. Should they be closed as dupes if the new answers are both different and usefull?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should tell the user to post their answer on the canonical version of the question, rather than posting it on duplicates.  The whole point of having a feature to close questions as duplicates is to keep the answers all in once place, so that people don't need to look over tons of different versions of the same question just to find all of the different solutions people have for a given problem.

If you really feel that the answer is that useful of an addition to the canonical, you could also flag the post and ask a moderator to merge the questions, rather than trying to rely on the answer author(s) to move their answers.

Comment: This is what makes more sense to me. I especially like it that you say the user that votes to close (or someone that notices other usefull answers) should "flag the post and ask a moderator to merge the questions".

Comment: Can't moderators migrate answers to another questions *if it's a duplicate*? Asking the users seems really amateur.

Comment: @Knu I specifically mentioned the possibility of merging in the answer.   That said unless there are a lot of answers it's quite a lot easier for the one answerer to just copy-paste their answer onto the canonical, and has the bonus of reminding them that they should be going to the canonical to post answers in general, rather than always answering duplicates and hoping mods merge the questions.

Comment: @Servy most of the times the answers are posted before that happens: users didn't know about the duplicate(s).

Comment: @Knu A significant part of what is learned by needing to move your answer is that you should be looking for potential duplicate questions *and* voting to close such questions as a duplicate. A user with a silver tag-badge, like the one who answered the linked question (& 3/4 to gold), should have a *very* good idea when a question is a duplicate and they should be thinking about the possibility that a question is a duplicate any time they see a new question. That's part of the responsibility which comes with greater experience on Stack Overflow and greater experience in a particular tag.

Answer (score 4):

Dare I say, be careful.

Questions and answers are interpreted differently between an expert and someone seeking an answer to a question without having deep knowledge in some area.   I am happy to acknowledge that in the area of javascript I am learning and quite often duplicates have provided a nuance that was not apparent in the original question that was flagged as a dupe.

However having said this I am also concerned about the proliferation of duplicates and the potential harm that they cause to the integrity of the site.

@Hack-R's comment that we could merge by adding the comments may be a solution but a better solution could be to somehow include the dupe with its prominence being based on its acceptance.

Comment: One may also be able to artificially merge by re-posting (as a community wiki) a good answer from a closed duplicate question to its opened original question.